# What are the values of the first 27 components of this 3-dimensional /epsilon symbol? (Just list those that are different from zero)

Tags: cross-product

So the problem starts by defining 2-D cross product

$\vec u\times \vec v = u_1v_2 - u_2v_1$

Then it says "an alternative way to write this is..."

$$\vec u\times \vec v = \sum_{ij}^\ \epsilon ^{ij}u_iv_j $$

Where $\epsilon$ is defined as

$ \epsilon_{12} = 1$

$\epsilon_{21} = -1 $

$\epsilon_{11} = \epsilon_{22} = 0 $

Then it throws the 3D representation at me as

$$(\vec u \times \vec v)_i =  \sum_{jk}^\ \epsilon _{ijk}u_jv_k $$

So they want the first 27 of this 3D sequence

Any explanation on the 3D  representation would be helpful, I somewhat understand the 2D one

Comment: This is called the [Levi-Civita symbol,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) and the Wikipedia article probably explains everything you want to know about it.

Comment: It is just a way to denote what you already know how to do with the cross product. For example, the first component is $u_2 v_3 - u_3 v_2$, so $\epsilon_{123}=1,\epsilon_{132}=-1$, and the other seven $\epsilon_{1jk}$ are zero.

Comment: So the components I am listing are just a series of 1's and -1s?

Comment: Yes. Six of them, in fact.